# Liquibase cannot find changelog file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I have following error with our spring boot 2 application:

> Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Error Reading Migration File: class path resource [src/main/resources/changelogs/changelog-1.0.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
>       at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parseToNode(XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java:118)
>       at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:15)
>       at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.include(DatabaseChangeLog.java:525)
>       at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.handleChildNode(DatabaseChangeLog.java:334)
>       ... 190 common frames omitted

in application properties we have: `spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/changelogs/changelog-master.xml`

All scripts are structured in spring boot's resource folder `/src/main/resources/changelogs`

In `changelogs` fodler is master xml and changelog with changesets as well.

reference to changelog of changesets in master xml is like this:

`<include file="src/main/resources/changelogs/changelog-1-0.xml"/>`

I cannot find reason why this isn't work.

I tried `relativeToChangelogFile="true"` and in file use only `file="changelog-1-0.xml"` and this works, why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not include `src/main/resouces` in your path inside the master changelog; those directories are not reflected in the generated jar. Try just `changelongs/changelog-1-0.xml`.